# How to apply search filter for first and last name

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to apply search filter like Android mobile have in contact app. For example there is a contact named **Aakash sharma**. And in search bar I press starting latter of **Aakash** i.e **aa** and after space then I press last name i.e. **sh**. Please find attachment so that you can understand batter.[image] Please help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my code

```
EditText search_filter = (EditText) stn_dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.et_search_ds);
            ListView listView = (ListView) stn_dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.lv_search_ds);
            stn_adapter = new ListAdapterStation(
                    RetailerSelectionActivity.this, R.layout.station_list,
                    station_list);

            filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // Filter from my adapter
                    stn_adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    // Update my view
                    stn_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                }
            };
            search_filter.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            listView.setAdapter(stn_adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    stn_dialog.dismiss();
                    RetailerSelectionDTO retailerSelectionDTO = (RetailerSelectionDTO) station_list
                            .get(pos);
                    station_name = retailerSelectionDTO.getStation_name_c();
                    station_id = retailerSelectionDTO.getStation_id_c();
                    btn_station.setText(station_name);
                    btn_retailer.requestFocus();
                    new GetRetailerTask().execute();
                }
            });
```

And the Adapter is

```
private class ListAdapterStation extends ArrayAdapter {
    /**
     * List of Procedure
     * 
     */
    private ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> items;
    /**
     * Application Context
     */
    private Context mContext;
    /**
     * List of Procedure
     */
    private ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> originalItems = new ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>();

    private ListAdapterItemFilter filter;

    public ListAdapterStation(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<RetailerSelectionDTO> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.items = (ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>) list;
        this.mContext = context;
        cloneItems((ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>) list);
    }

    /**
     * cloneItems @
     * 
     * @param list
     */
    protected void cloneItems(ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> list) {
        for (Iterator<RetailerSelectionDTO> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            RetailerSelectionDTO p = iterator.next();
            originalItems.add(p);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Count
     */

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get Item
     * 
     * @param item
     * @return TranUserProcedureDTO
     */
    @Override
    public RetailerSelectionDTO getItem(int item) {
        RetailerSelectionDTO p = null;
        p = (items != null ? items.get(item) : null);
        return p;

    }

    /**
     * Get View
     * 
     * @param position
     * @param convertView
     * @param parent
     * @return View
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.station_list, null); // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }
            RetailerSelectionDTO retailerSelectionDTO = items.get(position);
            if (retailerSelectionDTO != null) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_station);
                textView.setText(retailerSelectionDTO.getStation_name_c());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ListAdapterItemFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private class ListAdapterItemFilter extends Filter {

        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            /**
             * Initiate our results object
             */
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            /**
             * No prefix is sent to filter by so we're going to send back
             * the original array
             */

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                results.values = originalItems;
                results.count = originalItems.size();
            } else {
                /**
                 * Compare lower case strings
                 */
                String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                final ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> filteredItems = new ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>();
                final ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> localItems = new ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>();
                localItems.addAll(originalItems);
                final int count = localItems.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final RetailerSelectionDTO item = localItems.get(i);
                    final String itemName = item.getStation_name_c()
                            .toLowerCase();
                    if (itemName.contains(prefixString)) {
                        filteredItems.add(item);
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                results.values = filteredItems;
                results.count = filteredItems.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        /**
         * 
         */
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence prefix,
                FilterResults results) {
            /**
             * noinspection unchecked
             */
            final ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO> localItems = (ArrayList<RetailerSelectionDTO>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            /**
             * Add the items back in
             */
            for (Iterator iterator = localItems.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                RetailerSelectionDTO gi = (RetailerSelectionDTO) iterator
                        .next();
                add(gi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post code of `BaseAdapter` which you are using to show the list

Comment: Mehul please see updated question

Comment: Post code of `ListAdapterStation`

Comment: Now please find my updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the prefix and itemname into words and then match it.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final RetailerSelectionDTO item = localItems.get(i);
                final String itemName = item.getStation_name_c()
                        .toLowerCase();
                final String[] componentsItemName = itemName.split(" ");
                final String[] componentsPrefixString = prefixString.split(" ");

               // now here, you should match each word of prefix with each word of itemname 
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much mehul....Yesterday's night I got this. Same thing I did and then after split, I passed the splited words in query with  `WHERE` and `LIKE` clause. Now its working properly..Thanks once again..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use autocomplete textview. 
Refer this link http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Comment: No you are not getting me...I mean to say. look in image as per example there is contact saved Aakash sharma and in search filter I am pressing only "aak sh" still I am getting right result. I want that thing. Please help me.